# Bisection function returning the correct values with only some functions

Tags: python, numpy, bisection

When i apply my bisection to a numbers in a function it only returns the correct values with certain functions.

```
import numpy as np

def x_2(x):
    return x**2-5


def x_sin_exp(x):
    return 0.5 + -(x + np.sin(x)) * np.exp(-x**2.0)


def bisection(f: callable, a: float, b: float, tol=0.001, maxiter=100)-> tuple[float, int]:
    r=(a+b)/2
    for nit in range(maxiter+1):
        r = (a + b) / 2.0
        if np.abs(f(r))<tol:
            return (r,nit)
        elif f(a)*f(r)<0:
            b = r
        else:
            a = r
        

    return (r,nit)
```

For example, when apllying the x_2 it works correctly, but not with x_sin_exp as shown bellow:

`bisection(x_2,-3,3)` returns correctly (-2.236083984375, 12)
`bisection(x_sin_exp,-3,3)` returns incorrectly (3.0,100)

I have tried checking the symbols on the bisection function, and drawing them to check if the first outputed values are correct. The main problem is when it has to enter the else part of the function, it never does. I have tried with an other elif, but doesnt correct it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem in your code arises from the initial choice of ( a ) and ( b ) for the function `x_sin_exp`. The function `x_sin_exp` does not have a root in the interval ([-3, 3]) such that ( f(a) \times f(b) < 0 ). Therefore, your bisection method does not enter the "else" part, and you get incorrect results.

First, make sure ( f(a) \times f(b) < 0 ) before running the bisection algorithm. Second, it's good to check for cases where the function at the endpoints is already within the tolerance.

Here's a revised version of your function:

```py
import numpy as np

def bisection(f: callable, a: float, b: float, tol=0.001, maxiter=100) -> tuple[float, int]:
    if f(a) * f(b) >= 0:
        raise ValueError("f(a) and f(b) must have different signs.")

    for nit in range(1, maxiter + 1):
        r = (a + b) / 2.0
        if np.abs(f(r)) < tol:
            return r, nit
        elif f(a) * f(r) < 0:
            b = r
        else:
            a = r
    return r, nit
```

Now, calling `bisection(x_sin_exp, 3, 3)` will raise a `ValueError` with a message explaining that ( f(a) ) and ( f(b) ) must have different signs.

Comment: If the endpoints don't have different signs that doesn't mean there is no root in that range. Really, the code should raise an error if the endpoints have the same signs since the bisection method requires that the endpoints have different signs in order for it to possibly work.

Comment: You're correct. The assumption \( f(a) \times f(b) < 0 \) is a requirement for the bisection method to work, not a guarantee that there is a root in the interval. If \( f(a) \times f(b) > 0 \), the method is not applicable, and an error should be raised. Please see the above modified code that does just that.

Comment: I think your check should just be if it's greater than 0. If it's equal to 0 (unlikely because we're dealing with `float`s), then that might mean one of the endpoints is a root. Speaking of that, you mentioned checking the end points but don't actually do it. Before the `for` loop there should be a check if `abs(f(a)) < tol`. Same for `f(b)`.